Unable to reproduce primary key error on 'create if not exists sql'
This API endpoint persists a user's "like" using a 'create if not exists' sql:
if not exists(
    select 1 from likes 
    where UserId = @UserId and EntityId = @EntityId and EntityType = @EntityType)

insert into likes (UserId, EntityType, EntityId) 
values (@UserId, @EntityType, @EntityId)

The Likes table has no Id col, but rather has a primary key defined by: (UserId, EntityType, EntityId).
It works as expected...I've tested this both through 1) querying the database directly and 2) through the deployed API and it works as expected. If the like already exists, the database stays exactly the same.
However, I recently encountered this error:

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Likes'. Cannot insert
duplicate key in object 'dbo.Likes'. The duplicate key value is (19,
1, 113). The statement has been terminated.

I'll also mention that the server is running Azure Sql.
I can't reproduce this error. Please help me understand how this can happen.
Thank you.

This looks like a race condition. If two threads can enter this code near-simultaneously, they could both pass the IF condition and therefore both attempt to execute the INSERT INTO statement. The first will succeed; the second will fail because the primary key value now exists (having been written by the first thread). You will need to implement some kind of thread safety, perhaps with a lock.

You might want to look into a MERGE statement instead of an if.

This is a classic race condition, "check then do". Consider what happens if two database connections try to do the same thing at roughly the same time.



Connection A
Connection B




if not exists...




if not exists...


true




true


insert...




insert...


success




duplicate



To avoid this, "do then check". Do the insert and catch the duplicate key error.
